# How to fetch the file metadata using file path in flutter

Tags: flutter, file, dart, picker

All
I have flutter requirements like I need to display the Image/video selected from the gallery, along with the media date/month/year of capture or metadata of the media.
Before flutter upgrading, i was using the file picker default method so I was getting the data but after upgrading the flutter 2 in file picker the method is not working prperly. Please guide me with this issue.
Advance Thank You.